# Getting request for member not a structure or union error

Tags: c, pointers, struct, stack

I am trying to implement a stack. I have the following stack struct:

```
struct stackNode 
{
  char data;
  struct stackNode *nextPtr;
};

typedef struct stackNode StackNode; 
typedef StackNode *StackNodePtr;
```

When I try to use this for my pop method, I get a number of error messages. My pop method is:

```
char pop(StackNodePtr *topPtr )
{       
  if (IsEmpty(topPtr)) 
  {
    printf("Can't pop element from stack: stack is empty.\n");
    return 'n'; // arbitrary char to end if, will adjust this later.
  }
  char c = topPtr->data; //save data to be returned

  // temporary StructNodePtr to save data
  StackNodePtr temp; // temporary StackNodePtr
  temp = malloc(sizeof(StackNodePtr));
  temp->data = topPtr->data;    //line 52, first error
  temp->nextPtr = topPtr->nextPtr;

  //replace values in topPtr, this section I have yet to debug, is likely faulty.
  topPtr->data = temp->nextPtr->data;   //line 56, third error
  topPtr->nextPtr = temp->nextPtr; 

  free(temp);      
  return (c);
}
```

I get the following error messages:

```
52:22: error: request for member ‘data’ in something not a structure or union
53:25: error: request for member ‘nextPtr’ in something not a structure or union
56:10: error: request for member ‘data’ in something not a structure or union
57:10: error: request for member ‘nextPtr’ in something not a structure or union
```

If I make temp a StackNode (and adjust -> to . accordingly), I get the error `"request for member ‘nextPtr’ or ’data’ in something not a structure or union"`. In the question given to me, `topPtr` must me a `StackNodePtr`.

Can someone help me trouble shoot this?

Comment: The preferred solution: read through your entire program, paying very careful attention to pointers to structs vs. structs and how you're using each, and fix the places you're treating one like the other or the other like the first. For example, `topPtr->data` would be great of `topPtr` were actually a pointer to a StackNode, but it's not... it's a pointer to a pointer. `*topPtr->data` will get what you're looking for.

Comment: Your `malloc` most likely is also wrong. you should do `temp = malloc(sizeof(StackNode));` Generally it is usually considered bad practice to hide pointers in a `typedef`. You easily confuse the level of indirection.

Answer (score 2):

Your `topPtr` is pointer to pointer to struct (`StackNodePtr *topPtr` = `struct stackNode **topPtr`). So you should write `(*topPtr) -> data` instead of `topPtr -> data`.

In fact, the line `char c = topPtr->data;` should also cause an error.

Comment: I am so grateful right now! That fixed it! Thank you so much! I can't believe I missed that. Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: Did not know I had to wrap the struct in parenthesis.  Good stuff.